# quicksort python implementation fails without extra condition on left partition

Tags: python, quicksort

I tried to write an implementation of quicksort in python (there are quite a few available here, but my goal is to try on my own without copy/paste, just to practice going from the pseudo-code to the real code).

```
test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]

def partition(arr, istart, pivot):
    while pivot > istart :
        if arr[pivot] <= arr[istart]:
            arr[istart], arr[pivot - 1], arr[pivot] = arr[pivot - 1], arr[pivot], arr[istart]
            pivot -= 1
        else:
            istart +=  1

    if (pivot + 1 < len(arr) - 1): # right partition
        partition(arr, pivot + 1, len(arr) - 1 )

    if (pivot - 1  > 0)  and (pivot < len(arr) - 1) : #left partition
        partition(arr, 0, pivot -1)

    return arr    


def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr
    else:
        return partition(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)
```

For the left partition, I have to add a condition `(pivot < len(arr) - 1)` to get the code to work, otherwise I get the follwoing error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.
I can't understand why I need the extra condition: the pivot for the left partition should decrease as more and more elements on the left gets ordered. So, why do I need that condition?

Comment: You can just use the `sorted()` function in Python. Or are you trying to make it from scratch?

Comment: I am trying to make it from scratch as an exercise.